# PropertyGrid missing textChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having an issue with the propertyGrid.

I have a class called DummySettings that is mapped to the propertyGrid
I have a property "Name"

When typing something in the propertygrid EG the Name property I would like to raise an event that "TextChanged"

Despite implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged event and raising it and despite hooking all sorts of events I can think of on the propertyGrid
none of this events fires when A text changes.

Am I missing the obvious?

## EDITED

Psuedo Code

```
   public class DummySettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
            {
                private string name;


                [DisplayName("Name")]
                public string Name
                {
                    get { return name; }
                    set
                    {
                        if (name != value)
                        {
                          name = value;
                         OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                        }
                    }
                }

                public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
                {
                    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }



        //UserControl
    public partial class DummyControl : UserControl
    {
     private DummySettings settings;

     ///Constructor
    public DummyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        settings = new DummySettings();
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = settings;
        settings.PropertyChanged += OnDummyPropertyChanged;


     //All the events I have hooked up but not firing when text is changed 
    private void OnDummyPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
          btnToEnable.Enabled = HasName();
    }        
     private void propertyGrid1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
               btnToEnable.Enabled = HasName();
    }

    private void propertyGrid1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        btnToEnable.Enabled = HasName();
    }

    private void propertyGrid1_SelectedObjectsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          btnToEnable.Enabled = HasName();
    }


    private void propertyGrid1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
         btnToEnable.Enabled = HasName();
    }

      private bool HasName()
    {
        return settings.Name.IsNotNullOrEmpty();
    }
```

Comment: "Am I missing the obvious?" - How would we know this without code to review?!

Comment: Hi,Added code to give you an idea.The reason I did not add code because I thought somebody would say "oh you need to hook that event".The PropertyGrid does not seem to have a textChanged firing the same way a text box does on a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PropertyValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.propertyvaluechanged.aspx) event to get notified of selected object property changed in PropertyGrid. So, when you are changed `Name` property value from "Foo" to "Bar", this event will be raised:

```
void propertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // previous value is e.OldValue, "Foo"
    // property name is e.ChangedItem.Label, "Name"
    // new value is e.ChangedItem.Value, "Bar"
}
```

Comment: Yes I added that but it seems to fire only on Leave not when you type the text

Comment: Yes, this event fires when property value changed. When you are typing text, property value of objects has original value. It changes only when you leave input control

Comment: Are you able to get the `PropertyGrid.PropertyValueChanged` event to fire immediately after a keypress, as @user9969 describes? If so, I'm curious as to how, since I'm getting the same result: the event fires only after the control loses focus.

Comment: Correction: The event fires after the property being edited loses focus, not the entire control (for me at least).

Comment: Resolution: OK, I see now... the event fires after pressing Enter on the property being edited. I can live with that.